# JavaFX TreeView is empty

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I am new to working with `JavaFX`, and I am trying to create a `TreeView` to add to a `Tab`. When I add the `TreeView` to the `Tab`, however, it is empty. Below is the code that creates, populates, and adds the `TreeView` to the `Tab`.

```
public ResultView(List<WebPage> results, int resultNum) {
    this.pagesWithResults = results;
    urls = new ArrayList<String>();
    outputs = new ArrayList<>();

    resultsTab = new Tab("Result" + resultNum);

    resultTree = new TreeView<>();
    branches = new ArrayList<>();

    for(WebPage pageWithResults: pagesWithResults) {
        this.urls.add(pageWithResults.getURL());
        this.outputs.add(pageWithResults.getOutput());
    }

    TreeItem<String> root = new TreeItem<>();
    root.setExpanded(true);
    //resultTree.setShowRoot(false);

    for(int i = 0; i < urls.size(); i++) {
        branches.add(makeBranch(urls.get(i), root));
        //System.out.println(urls.get(i));

        for(int j = 0; j < outputs.get(i).size(); j++) {
            makeBranch(outputs.get(i).get(j), branches.get(i));
            //System.out.println(outputs.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }

    resultsTab.setContent(resultTree);
}

public TreeItem<String> makeBranch(String title, TreeItem<String> parent) {
    TreeItem<String> item = new TreeItem<>(title);
    item.setExpanded(true);
    parent.getChildren().add(item);
    return item;
}
```

The `TreeItems` are created in the `makeBranch` method, and added to the provided `parent`.

Here is what the `Tab` looks like when added to a `Scene`:

[Blank TreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q0cg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I figured it out. I have neglected to set the root of the `TreeView`. Adding:

```
resultTree.setRoot(root);
```

Adds the root to the tree, and makes the tree visible. Without that, I am returning an empty `TreeView`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a TreeTableView control
A basic implementation of a TreeTableView component in your application can be done by the following steps:

1 Create tree items.

2 Create the root element.

3 Add the tree items to the root element.

4 Create one or several columns.

5 Define cell content.

6 Create a tree table view.

Assign columns to the tree table view.

YOU DOESNT DO number 5 level

setCellValueFactory

Read this sample Completely

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm